# DataTrigger firing when it should not

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, enums, datatrigger

I have a custom ComboBox with this definition.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:InheritanceEnumValueConverter x:Key="inheritanceEnumValueConverter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <samples:MaterialEnumComboBox x:Name="materialComboBoxGenerateStatements"
                                      Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" Width="120"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                      IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                                      EnumSource="enums:YesNoInherit" Margin="52,0">
            <samples:MaterialEnumComboBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="samples:MaterialEnumComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="Text"
                            Value="{Binding Path=selectedModel.GenerateStatements,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding selectedModel.GenerateStatements}">
                            <DataTrigger.Value>
                                <enums:YesNoInherit>Inherit</enums:YesNoInherit>
                            </DataTrigger.Value>
                            <Setter Property="Text">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource inheritanceEnumValueConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="selectedModel.GenerateStatements"></Binding>
                                        <Binding Path="selectedModel.DefaultGenerateStatements"></Binding>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </samples:MaterialEnumComboBox.Style>
        </samples:MaterialEnumComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the custom ComboBox.  There is no significant XAML.

```
public partial class MaterialEnumComboBox
{
    private Type _enumSource;

    public Type EnumSource
    {
        get { return _enumSource; }
        set
        {
            _enumSource = value;
            this.SetBinding(ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = Enum.GetValues(_enumSource) });
        }
    }

    public MaterialEnumComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Here is the converter for the MultiBinding.

```
public class InheritanceEnumValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{  
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.All(x => x.GetType().BaseType != typeof(Enum)))
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        else
        {
            Enum typedValue = values[0] as Enum;
            Enum typedValue2 = values[1] as Enum;
            string strAbbr = typedValue.Description(); // based on the Description attribute for the enum.

            if (typedValue != null)
            {
                if (strAbbr == "Inherited")
                    strAbbr = typedValue2.ToString() + " " + "(" + "Inherited" + ")";
                return strAbbr;
            }
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type enumTargetType = targetTypes.First();
        var enumValue = Enum.Parse(enumTargetType, value.ToString());
        return new object[] { enumValue };
    }
}
```

Here is the model.  The ObservableObject is from Galasoft.MvvmLight.

```
public class MyModel: ObservableObject
{
    private YesNoInherit _generateStatements;
    private YesNoInherit _defaultGenerateStatements;

    public YesNoInherit GenerateStatements
    {
        get { return _generateStatements; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _generateStatements)
            {
                _generateStatements = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("GenerateStatements");
            }
        }
    }

    public YesNoInherit DefaultGenerateStatements
    {
        get { return _defaultGenerateStatements; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _defaultGenerateStatements)
            {
                _defaultGenerateStatements = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DefaultGenerateStatements");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the enum.

```
public enum YesNoInherit
{
    [Description("No")]
    No = 0,  ///< &nbsp;
    [Description("Yes")]
    Yes = 1,  ///< &nbsp;
    [Description("Inherited")]
    Inherit = 2
}
```

The "DefaultGenerateStatements" property is always "Yes" for this example.
When the combo box first appears, the value is "Yes".
I change the value of the combo box in this order.

1. When I change from "Yes" to "No", the converter is not executed.  I expect this.
2. When I change from "No" to "Yes", the converter is not executed.  I expect this.
3. When I change from "Yes" to "Inherit", the converter executes, gets the value of DefaultGenerateStatements, and returns the text "Yes (Inherited)" to the combo box.  I expect this.
4. When I change from "Inherit" to "Yes", the text "Yes" appears in the combo box as it should, but the converter is executed.  I'm not sure if the converter should execute.
5. When I change from "Yes" to "No", the text "No" appears as it should, but the converter is executed.  I don't believe the converter should execute.
6. After this, any change results in the converter being executed.

For steps 4 and 5, the DataTrigger fires when I don't think it should.  Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You should be able to just use `Value="Inherit"` in the trigger.

Comment: H.B., I did that and got the same result.  That was actually how the code was when I was given my current task.  I got the Value definition I used in my post from another SO post.

Comment: Of course you get the same result, it does the same thing. That's why this is a comment, not an answer...

Comment: I would debug the converter. You cast values using `as`, but don't __immediately__ check if they are not null. Besides, where did the enum's `Description` come from?

Comment: mechanic, my apologies.  I put a comment in the submitted code; my submission already has a lot of code in it..  It comes from an extension method that uses the DescriptionAttribute from System.ComponentModel.  I have debugged (didn't detect any null values), but I can certainly do more debugging.

Comment: More debugging did not help me find a solution.